# Cannot start SQL Server service. Need to create tempdb on new disk

Tags: sql-server

We had a SQL 2K server with tempdb set to a separate disk than SQL and OS. That disk had a problem and I need to start SQL with everything pointing to the C drive with SQL and the OS. At this point the service won't start because it's looking to create the tempdb on the other disk, no longer available.

Mounting a new disk and assigning the same drive letter as the old one is not an option at this point.

Comment: Here is how you can create a new tempdb: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288809

Comment: @Raj More, the KB you posted is for suspect tempdbs. My problem is a non-existent tempdb. The server won't even start if it can't create the tempdb. The problem is that the server is set up to create the tempdb on a non-existent disk.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt, and "mount" an existing folder as your missing drive letter.  For example, if TEMPDB *was* on G:, then try:

```
md d:\tempdbdisk
subst g: d:\tempdbdisk
```

You may need to create the directory structure that used to appear under **G:\** under **D:\TEMPDBDISK**.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put a new disk and assign the same drive letter just to start the service and transfer the files (tempdb and templog).

In this case, after the connection to the DB use this script:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = '{new location}\tempdb.mdf');
GO
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = '{new location}\templog.ldf');
GO
```

Don't forget to restart the service after running the above.

Look [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2342/sql_server_2005_move_tempdb/) for details.

Comment: I don't want to change the location at this point. The SQL server is not starting. I just need to know how to start the service if the tempdb create location is not available anymore.

Comment: @Parkyprg - is adding a new disk with the same drive letter the only option? At this point, I'm looking at other alternatives.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible without starting the service.

Comment: @Joel: Check Gail Erickson's last post on page (almoust down at the end).
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/82bd0c60-fa53-4870-98ec-3aa031e075ca - maybe you can use the second option.

Comment: Ended up with the 'new disk' solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's too late, but there's a document in Books Online titled "[Moving System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx)" that may be of use to you in the future.